# Quartz scheduler. Schedule job during asp.net application start

Tags: c#, asp.net, task, scheduler

I want to use task scheduler to create thread during application start.
I made it thanks to [this](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx/) and [this](http://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2011/06/webactivator-how-to-control-order-of.html), but something goes wrong and job is not running, of course is initialized before.

My class which is run before start:

```
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(
typeof(Application.App_Start.TaskScheduler), "Start")]
namespace Application.App_Start
{
    public static class TaskScheduler
{
    private static readonly IScheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().GetScheduler();

    private static void CreateTaskToDeleteTmpFiles(Object sender)
    {
        scheduler.Start();

        //Create job which will be add to thread
        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<DeleteTmpJob>()
            .WithIdentity("ClearTmpFiles")
            .StoreDurably()
            .Build();

        //Create thread which run the job after specified conditions
        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity("ClearTmpFiles")
            .StartAt(DateBuilder.FutureDate(1, IntervalUnit.Second))
            .Build();

        //Add Job and Trigger to scheduler
        scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);

    }


 }
}
```

My job class:

```
public class DeleteTmpJob : IJob
    {
        private IDocumentStore documentStore;
        private IUploaderCollection uploaderCollection;

        public DeleteTmpJob(IDocumentStore _documentStore, IUploaderCollection _uploaderCollection)
        {
            documentStore = _documentStore;
            uploaderCollection = _uploaderCollection;
        }

        public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
            documentStore.ClearTmpDirectory();
        }
    }
```

Job is not running

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using an empty constructor for your job?

> "Each (and every) time the scheduler executes the job, it creates a new instance of the class before calling its Execute(..) method. One of the ramifications of this behavior is the fact that jobs must have a no-arguement constructor."

You may need to implement your own JobFactory to allow you to use DI. How you implement it depends on which library you are using.

> "When a trigger fires, the JobDetail (instance definition) it is associated to is loaded, and the job class it refers to is instantiated via the JobFactory configured on the Scheduler.The default JobFactory simply calls the default constructor of the job class using Activator.CreateInstance, then attempts to call setter properties on the class that match the names of keys within the JobDataMap. **You may want to create your own implementation of JobFactory to accomplish things such as having your application's IoC or DI container produce/initialize the job instance**."

source: [see here](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/more-about-jobs.html)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, when I deleted constructor job worked. First try to call base constructor, if it is still not working try to delete constructor.

Comment: Ok, you are right, Job is running after remove the constructor.